# Can I return fields from an insert select that were not included with the insert?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.5.

I have a table `base` with some records:

```sql
CREATE TABLE base
(
    id    serial NOT NULL
  , thing varchar
  , copy  varchar
);
```

I want to insert a subset of those records into the table `new`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new
(
    id        serial NOT NULL
  , new_thing varchar
  , new_copy  varchar
);
```

`new` doesn't have a column to store `base.id`. But I would like to be able to map from `new.id` to the `base` row that the `new` row was created from:

```sql
CREATE TABLE base_to_new
(
    base_id int NOT NULL
  , new_id  int NOT NULL
);
```

This is the gist of what I want, but it doesn't work:

```sql
WITH new_rows AS
(
  INSERT INTO new
  (
    , new_thing
    , new_copy
  )

  SELECT
      thing
    , copy

  FROM base

  WHERE copy = 'yes'

  RETURNING
  (
      base.id AS base_id
    , new.id  AS new_id
  )
)

INSERT INTO base_to_new

SELECT
    new_rows.base_id
  , new_rows.new_id

FROM new_rows
;
```

The schema of `base` and `new` is not alterable.

I also want to avoid the following, because in reality, there are many more 
fields than in the example tables, the tables are very large, 
and let's be real, doing a bunch of comparisons is lame.

```sql
INSERT INTO base_to_new

SELECT 
    base.id
  , new.id

FROM base

LEFT JOIN new
  ON  thing = new_thing
  AND item  = new_item 
  AND stuff = new_stuff
  AND last  = new_last
;
```

Here is a SQL fiddle with schema and some data:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bbb9d

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works assuming that `base.thing` is unique:

```
with sel as (
    select *
    from base
    where copy = 'yes'
),
ins as (
    insert into new (new_thing, new_copy)
    select thing, copy
    from sel
    returning *
)
insert into base_to_new
select sel.id, ins.id
from sel
join ins on sel.thing = ins.new_thing;
```

Btw, I do not like the model as really troublesome. Storing `base.id` in `new` is simpler and much more natural. I would also avoid the words `new` and`copy` for table or column names as they have their own meaning in Postgres.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not solve my problem. If you saw my note at the end, the number of field comparisons I would need to do to ensure that the row from `base` is the same as the one inserted into `new` is too large. Additionally, there are already rows in `new` that would match these conditions.I need access to `base.id` in the insert.

Comment: You are trying to solve problems which never arise in a better design, see the note in my answer.

Comment: We don't always have the luxury of working with the ideal design! Sometimes we are working with legacy software that has tables with hundreds of columns and millions of rows, and we just have to find a solution that works.Thanks anyway!